# How to change embedded video size and alignment on ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm embedding a youtube video in one of my notebooks, and I'm not pleased with the size of the embedded video and the alignment.

I'm using

```
from IPython.display importYouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo("U3iNcBtycaQ")
```

To embed the video, but I would like to align the video window to the center and change it's size to something bigger. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo('U3iNcBtycaQ', width=1024, height=576)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do that, but it is HTML based and not Ipython based:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/U3iNcBtycaQ frameborder="4"></iframe>
</div>
```

Will appreciate an answer using the Ipython APIs.